# How to put image uploaded in tkinter into a function?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, pytorch

I am trying to create a Python tkinter application where the user can upload an image from file and the image is put through a image segmentation function which outputs an matplotlib plot.

I have the image segmentation function, it takes two parameters: neural network, image file pathway.

```
from torchvision import models
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as T
import numpy as np


fcn = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet101(pretrained=True).eval()


# Define the helper function
def decode_segmap(image, nc=21):

  label_colors = np.array([(0, 0, 0),  # 0=background
               # 1=aeroplane, 2=bicycle, 3=bird, 4=boat, 5=bottle
               (128, 0, 0), (0, 128, 0), (128, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128), (128, 0, 128),
               # 6=bus, 7=car, 8=cat, 9=chair, 10=cow
               (0, 128, 128), (128, 128, 128), (64, 0, 0), (192, 0, 0), (64, 128, 0),
               # 11=dining table, 12=dog, 13=horse, 14=motorbike, 15=person
               (192, 128, 0), (64, 0, 128), (192, 0, 128), (64, 128, 128), (192, 128, 128),
               # 16=potted plant, 17=sheep, 18=sofa, 19=train, 20=tv/monitor
               (0, 64, 0), (128, 64, 0), (0, 192, 0), (128, 192, 0), (0, 64, 128)])

  r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)

  for l in range(0, nc):
    idx = image == l
    r[idx] = label_colors[l, 0]
    g[idx] = label_colors[l, 1]
    b[idx] = label_colors[l, 2]

  rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
  return rgb


def segment(net, path):
  img = Image.open(path)
  plt.imshow(img); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
  # Comment the Resize and CenterCrop for better inference results
  trf = T.Compose([T.Resize(256), 
                   T.CenterCrop(224), 
                   T.ToTensor(), 
                   T.Normalize(mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                               std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
  inp = trf(img).unsqueeze(0)
  out = net(inp)['out']
  om = torch.argmax(out.squeeze(), dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()
  rgb = decode_segmap(om)
  plt.imshow(rgb); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
```

I have not made the Tkinter GUI as I am unsure how I can take the image uploaded from file and convert it into a file path (string) and put it through the function. There is only one neural network for now, being `fcn`.

Comment: you can use `from tkinter import filedialog` and then use that to choose path for the image file  ```path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir='/Downloads', title='Select Photo', filetypes=(('JPEG files', '*.jpg'), ('PNG files', '*.png')))``` the file extensions are jpeg nd png as u can see and is case-sensitive

Comment: @CoolCloud hey thanks for the recommendation. I had a look at the documentation but I'm still a little confused, what must I do with `filedialog` for it to return a file pathway as a variable so I can pass it through the function? thanks again edit: just saw your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly import `filedialog` and `PIL`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
```

Now use a variable path (or anything) to define the path that is returned when you choose inside of a GUI.

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Downloads', title='Select Photo', filetypes=(('JPEG files', '*.jpg'), ('PNG files', '*.png')))
```

You can use any filetype you want by specifying it in the argument there with the title and '*.extension'. *NOTE THAT IT IS CASE-SENSITIVE*. Now your variable `path` has the path for the image and all you have to do is open it with PIL using

```
img = Image.open(path)
```

Just like you did in your code

Comment: Welcome to SO, happy coding :)

Comment: hey I've been experimenting with the program, however, I am not able to parse the file pathway through the segmentation function as it cannot obtain the image pathway from the function bind to the button which takes the user's image. I have tried global variables and classes, but have not succeeded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try someother method?u know tht if ur commanding a function to a button, then u have to use lamda right? hope youve done that,if still issue then jus try some other method without passing it as a argument mayb,im not into matplotlib so i really dont knw wt ur doing, but the image path ive used it in my code

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll definitely go and try adding lambda.

Comment: im as intrigued as you are, please do let me know :) and is there a way i can see your code with tkinter?

Comment: Thanks for following up, if you know how I could give you the code, I am more than happy to show you. However it's in a bit of a mess right now. I've decided to put the whole thing under one function seeing another person did something similar and see if that works out.